# 8 GB SD card shows up as only 6.47 GB after creating ext2 partition; how do I recover the lost space?

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card

I have an 8 GB SD card, on which I created a 1 GB ext2 partition. When I later formatted the card, the capacity of the card appeared as 6.47 GB.

How do I recover the lost space ?

Comment: If you're in Windows, try opening it in the partition manager and see if all the space is being used for the visible partition. For OSX, use `Disk Utility`.

Comment: @Huey It show as `6.5 GB(Used: 0%)` in `MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition`

Comment: Check it out in the `HP Disk Storage Format Tool` and the manufacturer's software. Those can sometimes detect the true capacity of a card and allow you to reformat it properly. It could be caused by bad sectors on the disk (try scanning it in Windows?) or a virus that's using up the remaining space (use a reliable antivirus and scan it).

Comment: Tried with `HP Disk Storage Format Tool`. But not worked.

Comment: my other suggestions?

Comment: @Huey SD card scan is OK and no virus.

Answer (score 3):

#### Windows does not natively support volumes after the first partition on removable media. For Windows to recognize the "missing" space, any additional partitions must be removed.  A simple way to fix this is to erase the partition table on the SD card so that it can be reinitialized.

- The correct size of the SD card as displayed by Windows should be about 7.45 GiB. It appears you created your ext2 partition at the end of the SD card, where it is ignored by Windows. As such, the apparent size of the card is about 1 GiB less than it should be.
- Under Linux, try using `dd` to zero out the partition table: `dd if=/dev/zero of=<device> bs=4096 count=1024`. Make sure you select the correct device as this will erase all data on the target device. Use the raw device and not one of its partitions (e.g. `/dev/sdc`, not `/dev/sdc1`); otherwise, this won't wipe the partition table.
- Once the partition table is wiped, you are free to reinitialize it in any partitioning utility.

#### Alternatively, a third-party partitioning utility or Linux virtual machine can be used to correct the partitioning on the card.

- A third-party partitioning program such as [Paragon Partition Manager](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/) can be used to simply delete the ext2 partition and resize the main partition to fill the card. (*Note: I'm not affiliated with Paragon Software.*)
- A virtual machine running Linux can also be used to manipulate the partition tables on the card if it has direct, low-level access to the device. Again, you'll want to remove the ext2 partition and expand the main partition to fill the drive. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) can be used for this purpose.
- Using third-party software (or `dd` under Linux), you can read the partition into a disk image so that the volume can be mounted on its own, independently of the flash drive. This allows you to save the data on the partition before you delete it from the drive.

Comment: To clarify, Windows will still recognize only the first partition; no way around that?

Comment: No workaround as far as I can tell. It's just not supported.

Comment: @DragonLord Thanks for your answer. I'm new to Linux. with what should i replace `<device>` in `dd if=/dev/zero of=<device> bs=4096 count=1024` ? in Ubuntu, my sd card path show as `/media/guest-HxZww1/7BA3-15EC`

Comment: @Bishan, type `mount` and you'll see which device is associated with that path. It should start with `/dev/`. Be 100% sure you've selected the correct device.

Comment: @fixer1234 and AT Dragon, So no 3rd party software can? How about a linux virtual machine within windows?

Comment: @barlop: Third-party software *can* repartition the flash drive, but Windows will not allow any volume other than the first one to be mounted. It's just a limitation baked into the Logical Disk Manager (and it's pretty stupid `:/`).

Comment: @DragonLord and a linux VM on Windows?

Comment: @barlop: Yes, if you grant it low-level access to the drive

Comment: @DragonLord and what if you hide a volume (I recall back in the day partition magic could hide a partition). so what if you hide the first volume of a usb would windows not show anything or would it show the second(thinking it's the first)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19778/discussion-between-dragonlord-and-barlop).

Comment: @DragonLord can i execute this `dd` command using terminal in android device ? Then with what should i replace `<device>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the Partition table. You can use fidsk tool, or gparted.
I recommend gparted, as many partition tables are supported there.